# Obtain client IP in docker in azure container

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

Is there anyone who can help me to obtain user client IP from docker container that runs on Azure container instance ?

My code gets only local IP of something , i guess it is revers proxy.
So ip is 10.240.255.106;
Is headers I also have host IP (Public container IP) but nothing more. 
Headers

> {"Cache-Control":["max-age=0"],"Connection":["keep-alive"],"Accept":["text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"],"Accept-Encoding":["gzip,
>   deflate"],"Accept-Language":["en-US,en;q=0.9,ru-RU;q=0.8,ru;q=0.7"],"Host":["23.99.249.54"],"User-Agent":["Mozilla/5.0
>   (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like
>   Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100
>   Safari/537.36"],"Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":["1"],"DNT":["1"]}

Is there a way to get real client IP?

Comment: I do not really know what do you mean the client IP?

Comment: Sorry. This is asp.net core Web API. I need to obtain user IP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, ACI doesn't preserve the client IP.
You can create a feature request in the user voice.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602224-azure-container-instances?filter=top&page=1

Answer (score 0):

To get the client IP in asp.net core inside the controller action:

```
var ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
```

Comment: Yes. That is right. But unfortunately inside of azure container(docker)  you will get ip of container.

Comment: Can you pass param `--network host` when you run the container so its runs on the host network and not on NAT?

Comment: Unfortunately no.They don't allow specify network setting. Or I don't know how to do this.